# Scala: why must use def for generic instead of var

Tags: scala

I have this scala code:

```
trait Monoid[A] {
  def op(a1: A, a2: A): A
  def zero: A
}

val stringMonoid = new Monoid[String] {
  override def op(a1: String, a2: String): String = a1 + a2

  override def zero: String = ""
}

def listMonoid[A] = new Monoid[List[A]] {
  override def op(a1: List[A], a2: List[A]): List[A] = a1 ++ a2

  override def zero: List[A] = Nil
}
```

My question is if I change from `def` to `val` in this case, Scala will not compile:

```
var listMonoid[A] = new Monoid[List[A]] {
  override def op(a1: List[A], a2: List[A]): List[A] = a1 ++ a2

  override def zero: List[A] = Nil
}
```

Please explain for me this.

Comment: `val` is used for constant values, `var` for changeable variables, and `def` for declaring a function.

Comment: And in your second example, you said you're using `val`, but I only see a `var`.

Comment: The other question and answers say nothing about generics, but that is being asked about here.

Answer (score 1):

A `var` stores a reference to a certain object (or a certain primitive value, to be complete). It doesn't make sense to have, for instance a

```
var list[A] = mutable.ListBuffer.empty[A]
```

Because it would enable you to treat the same instance of a list as different types of lists at the same time. Like in the following example:

```
val listInt = list[Int]
listInt += 42
val listString = list[String]
val str: String = listString.head // world implodes
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem there is that the listMonoid method is parametrized with the type A, that is not possible to do with a var or a val, you can not instanciate an object that is generic on the type, you need to specify what A is

```
var listMonoid = new Monoid[List[Any]] {
  override def op(a1: List[Any], a2: List[Any]): List[Any] = a1 ++ a2

  override def zero: List[Any] = Nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is wrong. Use of `val` or `var` will compile without error.

```
trait Monoid[A] {
  val op: (A, A) => A
  var zero: A
}

def listMonoid[A] = new Monoid[List[A]] {
  override val op = (a1: List[A], a2: List[A]) => a1 ++ a2
  override var zero: List[A] = Nil
}
```

Comment: I think the question is not about the signature inside the trait, it's about moving from def listMonoid[A] to var listMonoid[A]

Comment: @Mikel, you could be right. It's not obvious what the OP is asking. The question should probably be closed as _unclear_.